# Delayed job end of file reached error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job

This is happening while sending emails with delayed job

> end of file reached /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/openssl/buffering.rb:174:in `sysread_nonblock' /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/openssl/buffering.rb

I am getting this unusual behaviour where sometimes it works perfectly fine and sometimes it fails with the above error.

I am using `delayed_job` (4.0.0), `ruby` 1.9.3 and `rails` 3.2.13

This occurs in production server and the delayed job process is running.
However when i restart the delayed job, it sends mail initially, but after a while it fails.

Comment: Have you run this  command in terminal `rake jobs:work`

Comment: The error is happening in production server and the delayed job process is running. I even restarted it and initially it sends email but stops sending with EOFError eventually.

Comment: Seeing the same behavior. Did you manage to figure this out?

Comment: I'm also seeing this behaviour, anyone find a resolve?